# Add character to input unless input value is result of calculation

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript calculator which uses the following function to add characters to the display:

```
function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0"){
    input.value = character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
};
```

and this to add a number based on the button pressed:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], function(i, e) {
  $('#button-' + e).click(function() {
    addChar(this.form.display, e);
  });
});
```

The issue I am having is that the user has the ability to add digits to the end of the display value *AFTER* a calculation (which makes very little sense). For example, suppose I find the cosine of 8 rad, the calculator returns -0.14550003380861354. If I hit a number key after, this number is merely appended to the previous string (if I hit 2, for instance, the display will read -0.14550003380861354**2**).

I would like for the calculator to merely reset and display the value of the pressed key. If the pressed key is an operator, that's fine, as that allows users to work with the value they just obtained.

How would I go about amending one or both of these functions so that I can achieve the desired result?

Comment: FYI; `input.value` will ***never*** be `null`, it will always be a string

Comment: I would definitely **not** make this decision within `addChar()` — addChar doesn't (and _shouldn't_) know the context in which it was called.

Comment: @adeneo you are correct. I had a deleteChar function that would make it `null` once upon a time, but it has since been changed and I forget to amend this function to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When result is calculated, add some class to the input, for example `result`, and before adding char check if input has this class. If yes, clear the input and remove the class.

For example:

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], function(i, e) {
  $('#button-' + e).click(function() {
    if ($(this.form.display).hasClass("result")) {
      $(this.form.display).removeClass("result").val("");
    }
    addChar(this.form.display, e);
  });
});

$("#calculate-button").click(function() {
  $(this.form.display).addClass("result");
  // do calculation
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some "state" attribute to your calculator which indicates when a calculation result is being displayed. The behaviour of the input events is changed depending on the current "state" of your calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the input field to `<input type="number" readonly="readonly" />` by appending your button press logic with input? Like:

```
document.getElementById("numberInput").setAttribute("readonly","readonly");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say to use a boolean variable (eg: isResult)to store the information as to the this is a result or not. If this is a result, you replace by the new character. Your function would look like this:

```
    function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0" || isResult){
    input.value = character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
};
```

Comment: This almost works, but it does not reset on click of another button after a calculation. It simply doesn't add anything to the display.